# Ubuntu 20.10 stuck on GNU GRUB version 2.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, grubrescue, 20.10

I have installed Ubuntu 20.10, and after 3 days of working with it, I started to get stuck in the GRUB v2.04 menu and the OS won't boot.

If I type `boot` it shows this error:

```
You need to load kernel first.
```

I tried using `ls` on `/boot/grub` and this was the output:

```
grub> ls
(proc)(hd0)

grub> ls (hd0)/
error:unknown filesystem

grub> ls (proc)/
luks_script
```

If I type `set` by default it finds:

```
.......
root = hd0
prefix = (hd0)/EFI/ubuntu
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Ubuntu did a giant fail and may have formatted the entire disk with only GRUB on it (somehow). Try reinstalling Ubuntu, and if that didn't work, reboot into the Live CD, and use this in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T or Ctrl+Alt+F2):

```sh
fdisk -l # this lists the disks
```

Try adding the results.

Comment: Ty for answer this, bu before doing that, can i copy my works data to flash disk drive via try ubuntu live fd?